# Specific Value in a collection from mongodb using python?

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary

I want to access a specific numeric in my collection (mongodb) via python.

I want to access 'only' the distance value (204) based on the city "boston" without any key display of "Distance" word. 
Output intended: 204

Collection in mongodb (json files):

```
{User ID: 1,
Test_description:{"City":boston, "Distance":204,"high_temp":1}}

{User ID: 2,
Test_description:{"City":new york, "Distance":24,"high_temp":25}}
```

Program:

```
d=collection.find_one({"Test_description":{"$elemMatch":{"City":"boston"}}})

print (d['Test_description']['Distance'])
```

Error:

```
-->TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

But when i am using `print(d['Test_description'])` its giving me output `{City:voston,distance:204,high_temp:1}` which is not I want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using PyMongo.

### If there is only one result

```
distance = collection.find_one({'Test_description':{'$elemMatch':{'City':'boston'}}})['Test_description']['Distance']
```

### If there are multiple results

```
distance = [x['Test_description']['Distance'] for x in collection.find({'Test_description':{'$elemMatch':{'City':'boston'}}})]
```